# Probability problem with bar graph

Tags: probability

**Problem:**

In Exercise 9, the distribution came “out of a hat.” In this problem, we will again consider an experiment whose outcomes are not equally likely. We will determine a function $f(x)$ which can be used to determine the probability of certain events. Let $T$ be the right triangle in the plane with vertices at the points $(0, 0)$, $(1, 0)$, and $(0, 1)$. The experiment consists of picking a point at random in the interior of T, and recording only the x-coordinate of the point. Thus, the sample space is the set [0, 1], but the outcomes do not seem to be equally likely. We can simulate this experiment by asking a computer to return two random real numbers in $[0, 1]$, and recording the first of these two numbers if their sum is less than $1$. Write this program and run it for 10,000 trials. Then make a bar graph of the result, breaking the interval $[0, 1]$ into 10 intervals. Compare the bar graph with the function $f(x) = 2 − 2x$. Now show that there is a constant $c$ such that the height of T at the x-coordinate value $x$ is $c$ times $f(x)$ for every $x$ in $[0, 1]$. Finally, show that
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\space dx=1$$

---

Could someone check my reasoning below?

**My answer:**

Height $h$ of triangle $T$ is given by a function $h(x)=1-x$. We may(?) assume that $h(x)=f(x)\cdot p$, where $p$ is some (potentially crazy) polynomial. Solving for $p$:

$$p=\dfrac{h(x)}{f(x)}=\dfrac{1-x}{2-2x}=\dfrac{1-x}{2(1-x)}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

hence $p$ is just a constant, hence there exists a $c$ such that $h=c\cdot f(x)$.

As for the second part, I guess they just want the reader to note that as the interval gets broken into smaller and smaller subintervals, the bar graph's shape gets closer and closer to the shaper under $f(x)$. Hence knowing that an integral returns an area of a function, and that the sum of the bars must equal 1, the integral of $f(x)$ is $1$.

Or perhaps: $f(x)=\dfrac{h(x)}{\frac{1}{2}}=2 \cdot h(x)$. Area of $h(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ is $(1\cdot 1)/2=\dfrac{1}{2}$ by the triangle area formula, hence the area of $f(x)=2\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}=1=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\space dx=1$.

[100,000 trials]

[image: 100,000 trials]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We may(?) assume that $h(x)=f(x)\cdot p$, where $p$ is some (potentially crazy) polynomial.

If you were not told that $f(x) = 2 - 2x,$
why would you assume that it is a rational function
(the ratio of two polynomials, $h(x)$ and $p$),
as you have just assumed in the statement quoted above?

But since you *were* told to try comparing $f(x) = 2 - 2x$ with the
height of the triangle, and you were asked to show that $f(x)$ is
$c$ times the height of the triangle for some constant $c,$
you can "guess" the value of $c$ by means of your calculation of
$\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}.$
(You don't have to consider the possibility that this ratio will come out
to "some crazy polynomial"--or more precisely, if it *does* come out to
some crazy polynomial, you'll know someone messed up the problem statement.)
Maybe it's worth showing this calculation in your answer (just to show the grader that you had some idea how to figure out what you needed), 
but the usual style of proof doesn't explain how we "guess" things like which
particular constant $c$ will work;
the proof is just to take the constant $\frac12$ (never mind how you got it),
work out the formula for $\frac12 f(x),$
and show that this is the height of triangle $T$ at the given $x$ coordinate.

To show that $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx=1$, I would just substitute the formula of $f(x)$ and solve the integral like any integral of a polynomial in calculus.